# simple arithmatic

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic

in sexagesimal method 
1 rtangle =90 degrees then 0.942387rtangle =?

actually in unitary method 1 is the least count but if we get something like .95,.88.How to calculate this?

Comment: Are you saying that in base 60, 90 degrees is 1 "rtangle" (which I assume is some "unit" of angles)? I personally haven't heard about this, could you please edit your question to elaborate on this / make it more clear?

Comment: What do you mean by least count? Are you using some device?

Comment: in sexagesimal system 1rt angle is divided in 9 parts called degrees so 0.942387right angle contains how many degrees?

Comment: Should be 90 parts

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, if $1\unicode{x221F} = 90 \unicode{xb0}$,

$0.942387 \unicode{x221F} = 0.942387$ x $90 =  84.81483 \unicode{xb0}$

Also, $84.81483 \unicode{xb0} = 84\unicode{xb0} 48`53``$

Comment: answer is something like that 90/84.81483degrees,i can't understand from where this numerator came

Comment: sl loney trigonometry

Comment: chapter 1 example 2

Comment: yeah,but 84.81483degrees is alright why this is in a fraction form means this numerator 90.would you please elaborate it.

Comment: That is only because they want to express it as deg, min and sec

Comment: 0.942387x90=84.81483 degrees but this numerator 90 from where it came

Comment: To convert degrees to DMG format, you take the decimal part of the degrees and multiply by 60, and then take the decimal part and multiply by 60 again to get seconds. (I think this is what they have done, while skipping steps)

Comment: yeah right you are talking about something like this 84.81483x60=48.8898min then min to sec thats fine but putting all those in fraction form i really can't get it.

Comment: I haven't understood that part either, so try getting your teacher to explain it to you.

Comment: thanks for all this,but that is what i needed and coming to teacher,i i like to self learn